# Tag synonym [google-gsuite] to [google-workspace]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I apparently suggested the tag synonym so long ago that I cant remember doing it.

We still need the synonym approved.

[google-workspace/synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-workspace/synonyms)

Comment: And I still have an upvote on it :) Another SME here - please do, seems like we do not have enough users with the required score to see it through.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine the story of my life 

Comment: I'm undeleting this so that we have the record of the completed request; we don't generally delete completed requests.

Comment: @RyanM np i will remember that in the future 